# Adding some text after TRUE boolean

Tags: php, boolean

Is there any way to add a text after the TRUE boolean value, assuming code is :

```
(get_field('test') ? : 'false';
```

I need something like this :

```
(get_field('test') ? +'WORD' : 'false';
```

Comment: You could probably use a temp var to hold the value of `get_field('test')` and run your test (ternary) on that.

Comment: I suggest you look up the basics of how to use ternary operator

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Do you have any example, i'm newbie to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the result of `get_field('test')` is.

If it's a boolean, then this is probably what you want:

```
echo get_field('test') ? "true - and proud of it!" : "false";
```

The reasoning here is that it doesn't really make sense to echo a boolean value; you should just say whatever you want to say about it.

If it's not a boolean (and your question seems to suggest that it is not), then you'll probably need to save the value before the `echo` statement - otherwise, you'll execute the function twice:

```
$value = get_field('test');

echo $value ? $value . " - and proud of it!" : "false";
```

That's the only way to ensure that `get_field` is called once.

Now if you're doing this a lot, you could write yourself a helper function:

```
function resultOrFalse($value, $message)
{
    return $value ? $value . $message : "false";
}
```

Comment: That's great, but i think my approach was totally wrong, basically i have a field (test) that i want to show in the page +min example: 27 MIN  and when field was empty doesn't show up anything. my current code is : `echo '. (get_field('run_time') ?: '') .'`